# Google UTM query string delimiter beginning with a hash (#) instead of a question mark "?"

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

Here is what my URL with a UTM looks like. (for personal reasons, I changed a bit of the URL)

`www.mywebsite.com/personal/everyday/guide/digital-account/#utm_term=mywebsite online account&utm_campaign=mywebsite+brand+-+google++search++....`

I'm curious to know why the query delimiter is a # instead of a ? or ?&, that I've seen so much of my other UTM. Really hoping someone has experienced a similar issue while making a UTM and if they have any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics supports using ? or # for the utm parameters.

It can be better to use the # as it is typically ignored by crawlers, tracking scripts etc.

?& would be a mistake, but I suspect GA would still pick up the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you know why the "#" might be replacing the "?" when setting up in UTM?

Comment: It's not replacing it. It's an alternate way to specify them.

Comment: Also, the part of the URL after the `#` is not sent to your server in the request.